# getting error Module did not self register, I am using msnodesqlv8 and mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, npm, npm-install, msnodesqlv8

I tried all my ways but still am getting this below error. Few days ago it was working fine but don't know what happened suddenly. Not able to fix below error. Please help.

`Error: Module did not self-register: '\\?\C:\Users\naruto\Desktop\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\build\Release\sqlserverv 8.node'. at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1243:18) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1037:32) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1061:19) at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18) at C:\Users\naruto\Desktop\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\util.js:4:21 at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\naruto\Desktop\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\util.js:34:3) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1159:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1213:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1037:32) { code: ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED }`